# magento 2.1.7 not showing icon in admin panel

Tags: magento, icons, magento2

I have installed Magento2.1.7, icons are not showing in admin panel i have cleared browser history. when i click the product it showing me nothing.i am new in Magento. Please any suggestions .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: ok np  @Enigmativity :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-j4rpab1deM

1. Open your project folder and go to `app/etc/di.xml`
2. open the file `di.xml` and use your text editor to search `Symlink` (line 645)
3. Replace `Symlink` with `Copy` (C must be capital)
   i.e it becomes
   `...
   <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
   ...`
4. save the file and reload your browser (optional - clear your browser cache before reloading page).

That solved my problem, no need to delete any folder, watch the video link above.

Answer (score 1):

Use below command:

1:`rm -rf var/*`

2:`rm -rf pub/static/*`

3:`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

4:`chmod -R 7777 var pub/static`

Comment: should be chmod -R 777 var pub/static

Answer (score 1):

This problem exist if your magento installation breaks in the middle and installation done by try again.

```
php /bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php /bin/magento indexer:reindex
php /bin/magento cache:clean
php /bin/magento cache:flush
```

Note: php should be your `PATH` in my case `f:\xampp\php\php`

Comment: When running the deploy, I'm getting this

#0 /home/magento/webapps/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

and additional errors. Any idea what the reason is?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that css and fonts files are not generated properly in your Magento. Please do the following

1. Remove **pub/static**
2. run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** in your CLI.
3. Clear the cache and check.

Answer (score 0):

Run commands for static-content deploy & Indexing in the cmd.
1. /bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
2. /bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. /bin/magento cache:clean
4. /bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Remove all files from pub/static folder but not .htaccess

Go to app/etc/di.xml

```
Replace ('Symlink' --> 'Copy')

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\**Symlink**
```

by

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\**Copy**
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check php version. If php version is more than 7.0.X then magento 2 is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

check the admin panel language, and be sure to run di-compile in that language ex.:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US en_GB